# Chrome Extensions: Javascript not not running clearInterval();

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying the make a chrome extension in javascript. So far, my popup.js looks like this:

```
let bg;
let clock;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', butClicked);
    bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    //clock = document.getElementById("label1");
});


let timeStamp;
let isClockRunning = false;

function butClicked() {
    let test = bg.getURL();
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = test;

    timeStamp = new Date();
    isClockRunning = !isClockRunning;
    runCheckTimer();
}

function runCheckTimer() {
    var handle;
    if(isClockRunning == true) {
        handle = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
    else if(isClockRunning == false) {
        clearInterval(handle);
        handle = 0;
    }
}

function updateClock() {
    let seconds = bg.returnTimeSince(timeStamp);
    document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML = "Seconds: " + seconds;
}
```

The program works just fine when I click the button once; it starts the timer. But when I click the button the second time, timeStamp gets set to 0, but the updateClock keeps running at the same interval; the interval doesn't get cleared even though I'm toggling the isClockRunning boolean. It's almost as if javascript is forgetting to run the else if part in runCheckTimer(). How can I fix this?

EDIT: On a sidenote, am I doing the timer thing the right way? Or is there a better way to do it? I basically want a timer to keep ticking every second since you've pressed the button, and then when you click it again it'll stop and reset to 0.

Comment: `handle` will be `undefined` when the `else if` case runs. Scope it outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have scoped `handle` to `runCheckTimer`. When `runCheckTimer` starts, it will create a new `handle` every time.

Move `handle` outside of the function.

```
var handle;
function runCheckTimer() {
    if(isClockRunning == true) {
        handle = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
    else if(isClockRunning == false) {
        clearInterval(handle);
        handle = 0;
    }
}
```